# Generate non-overlapping permutations

Tags: random

Let `l` be a list

```
l = Flatten[Range[7] & /@ Range[12]]; (* 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,... *)
```

The question is to efficiently generate three random permutations from this list, like

```
p1 = RandomSample[l];
p2 = RandomSample[l];
p3 = RandomSample[l];
```

but with a very special property. The three lists may not have an equal value on the same position. In other words: every element of `Transpose[{p1,p2,p3}]` must have three unique values.

Comment: I guess you want "three **random** permutations"

Comment: You might want to look at how to generate *random derangements* and go from there.

Comment: If you want something **in**efficient: `p := Array[RandomSample[l] &, 3];p //. h : {{__} ..} /; Times @@ (Tr /@ Abs /@  Differences /@ Transpose@h) == 0 :> p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p = Table[, {3}]; (* 3 is the number of 'special' permutations. Note that this number cannot be greater than the number of unique elements of l *)
p[[1]] = RandomSample[l];
For[i = 2, i <= Length[p], i++,
   p[[i]] = p[[1]];
   Do[
     p[[i, j]] = RandomChoice[Complement[l, Table[p[[k, j]], {k, i - 1}]]],
   {j, Length[l]}]
]
```

This seems to be a method without trial and error. One could speed it up by storing the result of the complement for each i as it only changes a little for each next i.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is any useful, but this generates the 3 permutations and then check if the condition is met. Otherwise it starts again.

```
NestWhile[
    Table[RandomSample[l], {3}] &, 
    Table[RandomSample[l], {3}],
    !VectorQ[
        #,
        Length[DeleteDuplicates[#]] === 3 &
    ] &
]
```